# How to consume a promise and use the result later on with my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to async operations and js. Here is my question.
I have a Person class. I want to init Person instance using data that I get from an API call.

```
class Person { 
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I am making an API call using Axios. I get a response and want to use it in my class.

```
const res = axios.get('https://findperson.com/api/david');
const david = new Person(res);
```

I understand that res is a promise at this stage, and that I need to consume it.
How should I do it?
How can I take the response and use it properly?

Comment: You've already tagged your question with `async`/`await`, so it seems you know the correct approach. Can you show us the cde you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

axios.get() return a promise of an object which contains the returned data, status, headers, etc...

```js
async function getPerson() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('https://findperson.com/api/david');
    const david = new Person(res.data);
    // do something with david
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

or

```js
function getPerson() {
  axios
    .get('https://findperson.com/api/david')
    .then(res => {
      const david = new Person(res.data)
      // do something with david
    })
    .catch(console.log)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside another `async` function, or at the top level of a module or at the REPL (in node 16.6+ or some earlier versions with the `--experimental-repl-await` feature enabled), you can just use `await`.

```
const res = await axios.get('https://findperson.com/api/david');
```

That will wait for the promise to be resolved and unwrap it to store the contained value in `res`.

If you want to get the value out of the world of async and into synchro-land, you have to do something with it via a callback function:

```
axios.get('https://findperson.com/api/david').then(
  res => { 
      // do stuff with res here
  });
```

... but don't be fooled; without an `await`, any code that comes after that `axios.get` call will run immediately without waiting for the callback. So you can't do something like copy res to a global var in the callback and then expect it to be set in subsequent code; it has to be callbacks all the way down.

Comment: You have to wrap that `await` in an async function though or there's going to be an error.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
axios.get('https://findperson.com/api/david').then(res => {
        const david = new Person(res);
    });
```

Or in async function: (See async await for javascript)

```
const res = await axios.get('https://findperson.com/api/david');
const david = new Person(res);
```